# Saving product deletes tier price and group price

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I've got a problem when programatically saving a product.

While loading the product with help of the product collection or the model (by attribute), setting some value and then saving it, I'm losing the tier and group prices.

```
$productList = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/product' )->getCollection ()
  ->addFieldToFilter('color', $color)
  ->load();
foreach($productList as  $product) {
    $product->setColor($newColor);
    $product->save();
}
```

One can do a workaround by doing one of these:

1.Reload each product:

```
$productList = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/product' )->getCollection ()
  ->addFieldToFilter('color', $color)
  ->load();
foreach($productList as  $product) {
    $product = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct($product->getId());
    $product->setColor($newColor);
    $product->save();
}
```

2.Load tier and group price (source):

```
$productList = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/product' )->getCollection ()
  ->addFieldToFilter('color', $color)
  ->load();
foreach($productList as  $product) {
    $product->getTierPrice(); 
    $product->getGroupPrice();
    $product->setColor($newColor);
    $product->save();
}
```

minimal variant of reloading (for example) the tier price attribute (extracted from Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price::getTierPrice():

```
$attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('tier_price');
if($attribute){
    $attribute->getBackend()->afterLoad($product);
}
```

3.Add dummy values (source):

```
$productList = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/product' )->getCollection ()
  ->addFieldToFilter('color', $color)
  ->load();
foreach($productList as  $product) {
    $product->setTierPrice ( array (
        'website_id' => 0,
        'cust_group' => 2,
        'price_qty' => 3,
        'price' => 10 
    ) );
    $product->setGroupPrice ( array (
        'website_id' => 0,
        'cust_group' => 2,
        'price' => 10 
    ) );
    $product->setColor($newColor);
    $product->save();
}
```

All these workarounds have one problem: more database calls.
When often running scripts that update a lot of products, it is bad to have even more database calls only for **not** to lose the tier and group prices.

One can add the tier prices while building up the collection:

```
$productList = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/product' )->getCollection ()
  ->addFieldToFilter('color', $color)
  ->addTierPriceData()
  ->load();
foreach($productList as  $product) {
    $product->setColor($newColor);
    $product->save();
}
```

But by doing so, on save one will get a constraint violation error. It seems in this case Magento tries to save the exact same tier prices again.

Does anyone know a solution which loads the tier and group prices in the same query that is used by the product collection and does not trigger constraint violations on save?

I have also posted this question in the Magento part of StackExchange:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51848/saving-product-deletes-tier-price-and-group-price

Comment: I've come across this too, it's a bug in Magento definately present in 1.7, 1.8 and 1.9, and probably older versions.  I went for the reload method myself.

Comment: For me other custom attributes also disappear as PixieMedia says reload method solves this issue.